# InfoPath 2010 error on MOSS 2007

Tags: infopath, error, 2007, forms-services

We developed an Infopathc 2010 for (which include filters) and try to publish that on MOSS 2007.  However, we are gettig an error msg: "the form cannot be converted because it was designed for a later version of infopath forms services".

It appears to be an MOSS 2007 error so my question is if anyone has experienced this, and if not, is there an update for MOSS 2007 that we somehow missed.

Thx,
Henri

Answer (score 2):

Its going to depend on what functionality you used in your form. If you used components that are new to InfoPath 2010, such as the Contact Selector, you aren't going to be able to publish it in a MOSS 2007 environment.

John

Comment: John, thanks.  No, we don't have that control, or any other ActiveX added for that matter.  We have data link to an SQL2005 database and filters on a few fields.  There is an MSDN post explaining that an attribute (solutionFormatVersion) must be updated/set somewhere, but that is as cryptic as the original error message, at least to me....  (error #272 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958542(office.12).aspx)

So, no joy....:(